# Getting rid of borders on title page of a Rmarkdown project

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I'm adding a png image as the title to a report I'm writing. The image is A4 and loading correctly, but the page borders from the rest of the report are also impacting the title page so the image slips off the side:

[image]

I'm building the code in RMarkdown:

== report.Rmd

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      before_body: prebody-latex.tex
      in_header: preamble-latex.tex
    latex_engine: xelatex
---
\tableofcontents

\pagebreak
```

With the following tex files:

== preamble-latex.tex

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx,transparent}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\SetWatermarkText{}

\fancyhead[CO,CE]{}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{-10pt}

\let\origfigure\figure
\let\endorigfigure\endfigure
\renewenvironment{figure}[1][2] {
    \expandafter\origfigure\expandafter[H]
} {
    \endorigfigure
}

\newcommand{\blandscape}{\begin{landscape}}
\newcommand{\elandscape}{\end{landscape}}
```

== prebody-latex.tex

```
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{frontcover.png}
\end{titlepage}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For full page images you can use the LaTeX package `pdfpages`. To `preamble-latex.tex` add:

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}
```

And in `prebody-latex.tex` use

```
\begin{titlepage}
    \includepdf{frontcover.png}
\end{titlepage}
```